# Randomize from a made list

Tags: java, random

```
ArrayList<String> listArray = new ArrayList<String>();

private void AddToListActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String addTo = txtAdd.getText();
    listArray.add(addTo);
}                                        

private void randomPickerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

}
```

In the button randomPicker, I want to print out one of the random strings I added in my array. Can you guys help me out with what I should write inside that button?

I tried:

```
   String random = (listArray[new Random().nextInt(listArray.length)]);
    System.out.println(random);
```

It said i couldn't use `nextInt`

Comment: Call [`Collections.shuffle(List<?>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) **once**, then iterate normally.

Comment: Cannot find symbol on "shuffle"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this

```
Random ran = new Random();
String random = (String) list.get(ran.nextInt(list.size()));
System.out.println("random :"+rdom);
```

Answer (score 1):

`String random = (listArray[new Random().nextInt(listArray.length)]);`

You are using syntax for arrays, and your `listArray` is actually an `ArrayList` (you are doing somewhere else `list.add()` that's how I guess). You need to invoke a get method of the `ArrayList`, like this:

`String random = listArray.get(new Random().nextInt(listArray.size()));`

Notice the `size()` method, `length` property is just for arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I learned alot by just reading your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what you want this stuff for. But, generally there's two things. You can use the class `Random` to pick a random index in your `ArrayList`.

Or you can use the  collections `java.util.Collections.shuffle()` method.

```
public static void shuffle(List<?> list)
```

To shuffle the entire List.

```
Random random = new Random();
int index = random.nextInt(listArray.size());
String random = listArray.get(index);
```

My guess is you're coming from c++. The ArrayLists in java are backed by actual arrays. But, they are not accessible. You don't call .length on them, but .size()

Comment: Yeah, size() instead of length(), thought it would mean the same thing in Java aswell :)

Comment: It's in there, but hidden. The String[] array backs the array class but it includes a bunch of pointers (that you are never allowed to see) to the String. So everything is encapsulated. You only treat it like an array for time complexity.